# Any way to obtain a product id with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, widget, e-commerce

I am working on a rails project that involves users embedding a widget onto a product page on  their separately hosted website. Lets say the widget would take the form of a script tag.

The widget would open another window with a form on it (hosted on the widgets origin website), and allow the user to attach information about that product that would then post to a database hosted on the site where the widget originates from.

So the product id on the product page and the product id on the widget website would match.

My question is this. How would one obtain the product id from the page where the widget resides? I need to pass parameters with the product id via the widget so I can update the correct product in the widgets origin database.

Hope this makes sense. What would be the approach to this?

Comment: What about setting a data-id field in the html and just accessing that via javascript?

Comment: Yeah i think for this to be implemented it will require some configuration from the user, like sending in the product id through a config var in the header

Comment: Do you supply the widget to the other sites? And do you control the products and the ids?  If so, it is very similar to how affiliate models work (cj, linkshare, amazon, etc.).  You could always provide a unique link in the widget that can track the source and product (you decode the link on your side) and then show the appropriate form to collect the additional data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use ERB to write into javascript source, just the same as using ERB to write into HTML source. So, just spit out the `@product.id` into the relevant portion of javascript code. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var productId = <%= @product.id %>;
  // Do whatever you want with productId here
</script>
```

Then just examine the source of the page to be sure of what you're outputting / as debugging.

Comment: That would work locally on the widget application, but how would I allow a user to embed a script on their page, so that the id is pulled from their code? I need to be able to generate the widget url on the users website that includes the parameters i need (product_id)

Comment: The user would need to supply their product id to the widget script somehow (only their app knows their product id, right?). If the product id doesn't change then you could have them hardcode it in a config section of your script. But if it could change then they would need to do something like the above. The harder alternative would be to have them set up almost an API-like endpoint where you could query their app for the product id when loading the widget script... but a configuration approach sounds easier to me.

Comment: thanks pdobb, that makes perfect sense, was hoping there may be some nifty way of accessing that data so that the widget would not require too much configuration by the user, but it looks like thats about as good as its gonna get. Thanks